# How to update a field based on the success of email sending

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to update the field "Success" based on the success of Email sending. How to update this?

N.B - the datasource is in manual save mode and a relational database.
So far I've this

```
var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem.item;

   google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
       status.text = error.message;
       success.Success = "Incomplete";

      })
      .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
       status.text = 'Email sent';
       success.Success = "Active";
       clearEmailForm();

      })

       .sendEmailMessage(To, subject, msg);


     app.datasources.ChangeSystem.saveChanges();
```

Comment: You need to incorporate your saveChanges inside both the success and failure functions. In your case your client script calls the server function and immediately moves on to saveChanges instead of waiting for the server function to complete.

Comment: ```google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
       status.text = error.message;
       success.Success = "Incomplete";
       app.datasources.ChangeSystem.saveChanges();
    
      })
      .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
       status.text = 'Email sent';
       success.Success = "Active";
       app.datasources.ChangeSystem.saveChanges();
       clearEmailForm();
    
      })
  
       .sendEmailMessage(To, subject, msg); ``` Tried this way. But still getting error  ```Cannot set property 'Success' of null```

Comment: Then your problem is with var success, not with actually saving the changes. I’m guessing that either your item is not loaded on the client. Where are you calling this script from? Presumably a button but what is the datasource of the button?

Comment: I've changed my Button's Datasource. Now It's not giving me any errors. But also, It's not updating  any info. It's just keeping my Default value, which was  "draft". The code is same as above comment. Please let me know which other info do you need. I will post it here.

Comment: Well, you need to keep in mind just attaching a datasource to a widget all it does is load the first however many records your page limit is set to into the client and then datasource.item just points to the currently selected item in that datasource which is typically the first one. How is your form setup that determines which ChangeSystem item the email is sent on?

Comment: so the button "send email", the datasource is "ChangeSystem" and onclick event is custom ``` var subject = widgets.timeTextBox.value ;
 var to= app.pages.Email.descendants.defaultEmail.value;                                                var msg =  "Description:\n\t\t"        + widgets.Objective.value;                                   sendMessage(to, subject, msg);
app.datasources.ChangeSystem.createItem();``` Where SendMessage is the clientscript function name. Which Calls the client script and send the email

Comment: Is there anything that references which ChangeSystem item is loaded? Maybe edit your question and show a screenshot of your form in design mode. Maybe your button datasource is pointing to the incorrect ChangeSystem item and therefore you no longer throw the error, but the status gets assigned to an incorrect ChangeSystem record. Alternatively instead of doing `var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem.item` do `var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem` instead and then modify your lines in success and failure to `success.item.Success = 'whatever here'`.

Comment: Rereading your last comment, why are you creating a record in ChangeSystem datasource? Are you not sending an email based on an existing record? For example lets take an invoice record and you have a status field whether the invoice has been emailed to the client, you would create the invoice and then have a button that emails the invoice or you would create the invoice and email it all in one step. If you do the one step function then you need to wait for the record to be created before you can pass it to anything especially if you want to update a status on the newly created item.

Comment: No, I am creating the record after email has sent. if the email don't deliver It'll still be saved but the status of success would be different. There are another button which saves only the draft. Later we can send the email too, But using different  send email button.

Comment: var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem worked for me now.